# Using shared_ptr for refcounting

Tags: shared-ptr

I have a class whose objects are extensively used using shared_pointers. However, I want to track the usage of these objects and when the refcount goes to a particular value I want to delete the object. How can we do this ? I was thinking of overriding the shared_ptr's destructor so that I can decrement the refcount when every shared_ptr reference goes away. However, looks like that is not possible. What are the alternatives ?

Comment: "However, I want to track the usage of these objects and when the refcount goes to a particular value I want to delete the object." - that's what `std::shared_ptr` does by default. It's the entire point of their existence. (If you mean deleting the object when the refcount hits some *nonzero* value, that sounds like a bad idea, and you'll have to provide a lot more context for anyone to provide a sensible answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You really wouldn't want to do that because if the refcount is greater than zero it means there are still pointers pointing to the object out there, probably intending to access it.

If you really wanted to do something like that, you'd have to make your own shared_ptr class, but I'd also add functionality for checking if the pointer is still valid since it might disappear on people.